# Test for comma delimited string, ignoring any encountered periods, say from real numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

The following works for a simple comma delimited string, that has no periods, but if periods in real numbers found it breaks.

`pattern = re.compile(r"^(\w+)(,\s*\w+)*$")`

How can I modify or change the above to ignore periods?  But still validate the given string is comma delimited?

A sample test string is `"23,HIGH,1.0,LOW,1.0,HIGH,1.0,LOW,1.0"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value can only be a number, and matching dots only would not be desired you can use and alternation to match either word characters or a number.

```
^(?:[+-]?\d*\.?\d+|\w+)(?:,(?:[+-]?\d*\.?\d+|\w+))*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[+-]?\d*\.?\d+` Match an optional `+` or `-`, then optional digits, optional dot and 1+ digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `,` Match the comma
  - `(?:[+-]?\d*\.?\d+|\w+)` The same pattern as in the first part
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat to also match a single occurrence
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7qjxQV/1)

Answer (score 1):

`\w` matches "word" characters: letters, digits and `_`. It doesn't match a dot. If you want to match dots as well, use `[\w.]` instead of `\w`:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"^([\w.]+)(,\s*[\w.]+)*$")
```

You might also want to add `-`, if you expect negative numbers. To put `-` in a character class, you either have to backslash escape it or make sure it's either the first or last character in the class:

```
[-.\w]
[\w.-]
[\w\-.]
```

Comment: Not sure I understand... the example string I provided fails using the given expression.  It 'sees' the periods, i.e. decimals.  If I change '\w+' to '\w' it still fails.  I know nothing about regular expressions... maybe used them rarely, almost never.  And, no negative numbers in the current use case, they will always be real, positive values.  So I see your answer as not working for what I need, give my misunderstanding?  I need real numbers to be accepted as valid values in the comma delimited string as the example illustrates, but the (new) expression not tripping over the periods.

Comment: @schorschi: Ok, I edited the answer to be more explicit.  At no point did I suggest changing `\w+` to `\w`. I suggested changing `\w` to `[\w.]`.

Comment: @rici it might just be better to suggest `.+` to handle other characters, like `#@`, etc. It seems like the CSV rows include both arbitrary string text and real numbers.

Comment: @YuChen: if it accepted anything, it would be pointless. It's supposed to veirfy that the line conforns to a particular data model, not arbitrary CSV. I could have recommended the use of a real CSV parser, but I think that's not what OP is looking for; they would still need to validate each field according to whatever rules they have. For a more precise answer, they would have to precisely specify those rules.

Comment: @rici, correct, I need to validate that the string is comma delimited, and not tripping over the periods... real numbers.  Greatly appreciate the detailed answer (revision).  Really helped my understanding, since I have very little experience with regular expression.  However, as the example string shows, strings not just numbers are expected/allowed.

Comment: Thanks! Again!  Forgot to mark the answer as accepted.